# How can I upload files asynchronously on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I've been looking for a way to achieve this behavior and I [found this sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/GmailUpload.aspx).

The trick in this project is that it changes the `form` target to an `iframe` created on the fly.

So far so good, I can get the `byte[]` on the server-side. But I need to change an image preview after the file is uploaded.

How can I get the `iframe` to update the main page? Would I have to save it on a file on the disk, make a javascript callback to change the image url? Is there another way to do this? What's recommended?

---

[This control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) suggested by vorrtex actually causes a full page postback, am I missing something or is it the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`AsyncFileUploader`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) and `UpdatePanel`. You have to save file on the disk but you can use C# for changing imageUrl.

Comment: Actually the page keeps getting a full postback. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems that such behaviour is prohibited: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/03/30/why-don-t-file-uploads-work-during-async-postbacks.aspx. Maybe this is reason why Google uses flash in Gmail.

Comment: I see, so I will have to do the callback on javascript... Thanks for this link it was very clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<script>` block to the page that gets loaded in the `<iframe>` that interacts with the parent page and updates whatever you need to.

Comment: AFAIK, it will allow to upload anything, except files.

Comment: @Valera: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: oops, I thought, that you are proposing to implement "async file upload functionality" using <script> and <iframe>, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project mentioned below to preview the image before uploading. Working sample is also attached.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/40858-Preview-Image-before-uploading-using.aspx

This uses AjaxControlToolKit's AsyncFileUploadControl and HTTPHandler to upload the image.